# How to exclude "Deleted messages" from Historylist

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am syncing the user's email according to last history_id and its working fine.
But sometimes it doesn't work and showing a message not found error. 
I have checked and found, It was syncing messages which get removed from INBOX or Bounced.

I have added one more parameter in $opt_pram array `'historyTypes'=>'messageAdded'` but still it's getting all the messages with deleted messages.
I have also tried with labelIds= INBOX but it's not working.

```
$opt_param = array('historyTypes'=>'messageAdded','startHistoryId' => $history_id,'maxResults'=>100);

$pageToken = NULL;
$histories = array();

do {
    try {
        if ($pageToken) {
            $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
        }
        $historyResponse = $service->users_history->listUsersHistory($user, $opt_param);
        if ($historyResponse->getHistory()) {
            $histories = array_merge($histories, $historyResponse->getHistory());
            $pageToken = $historyResponse->getNextPageToken();
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
} while ($pageToken);
```

In `$histories`, it's containing deleted messages as well.

I am looking for a solution where I can get all valid/existing messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `'historyTypes'=>'messageAdded'` will show you all messages added since the creation of the corresponding `startHistoryId`, even if those messages have been preposterously deleted.

As a workaround, I suggest you to make a second query for `'historyTypes'=>'messageDeleted'` and then compare the message Ids contained in the respective query responses and only sync the messages contained in the `'historyTypes'=>'messageAdded'` query, but not in the `'historyTypes'=>'messageDeleted'` query.